# Regex start with any number and it should end without zeros

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a Regex with groups that should group `1234.0500-` to `1234.05-`.
What I have tried is:

```
^([0-9]+)(\.)([1-9]*)0*(-?)$
```

but it does not match `1234.0500-`. Here is the example https://regex101.com/r/koSZoB/1. The regex should also group

```
1234.0000
0.9000
```

to

```
1234
0.9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your pattern, this part `([1-9]*)0*(-?)$` matches optional digits 1-9 followed by optional zeroes and then an optional hyphen at the end of the string. It will succeed until the first zero:

```
0500
^
```

But the match will fail as it can not match `(-?)$`

---

You could use 3 capturing groups and use those in the replacement.

After group 1, you could either match a dot followed by only zeroes which should be removed, or capture in group 2 matching from the dot till the lats digits 1-9 and remove the trailing zeroes.

```
^(\d+)(?:\.0+|(\.\d*[1-9])0+)(-?)$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(\d+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ digits
- `(?:` Non capture group, match either

  - `\.0+` Match a `.` and 1+ zeroes
  - `|` Or
  - `(\.\d*[1-9])0+` Capture `.`, 0+ digits followed by a digit 1-9 and match the following 1+ zeroes to be removed
- `)` Close group
- `(-?)` Capture optional `-`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KbtDEw/1)

There is no language tagged, but for example in Javascript

```js
const pattern = /^(\d+)(?:\.0+|(\.\d*[1-9])0+)(-?)$/;
[
  "1234.0500-",
  "1234.05500-",
  "1234.0550588500-",
  "1234.0000",
  "0.9000",
  "12.1222",
  "12.1222-",
].forEach(s => console.log(s.replace(pattern, "$1$2$3")));
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention the case `12.1222` and `12.1222-`. This should also matched.

Comment: @zero_coding Should there be changes to that format? The pattern does match match those formats, so in the replacement they will stay the same.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The format should stay the same. The last two numbers should also be matched.

Comment: @zero_coding You can also match the last 2 numbers making the zero optional `^(\d+)(?:\.0+|(\.\d*[1-9])0*)(-?)$` See https://regex101.com/r/dWPRfs/1

Comment: You are awesome. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The third capture group doesn't include zeroes meaning that the 0 in `05` is making the match fail.

I would suggest making the third capture group non-greedy by adding a `?`: `^([0-9]+)(\.)([0-9]*?)0*(-?)$` This will make it match the minimum amount of zeroes possible instead of the maximum. With the last group being greedy it should work.